# Double function not returning Double value?

Tags: java, double, return

```
public class Nitin12assignA6 {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        series ob = new series();
        ob.input();
        ob.findSum();
        ob.display();
    }
}
    class series {

        int x, n;

        double sum;

        series() {
            x = n = 0;
            sum = 0.0f;
        }

        void input() throws IOException {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.print("\nEnter the value of x = ");
            x = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
            System.out.print("Enter the value of n = ");
            n = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        }

        void display() {
            System.out.println("The sum of Series upto " + n + " terms is: " + sum);
            System.out.println();
        }

        long fact(int num) {
            if(num == 1) {
                return 1;
            }
            return num * fact(num - 1);
        }

        int power(int num, int exp) {
            if(exp == 1) {
                return 1;
            }
            return num * power(num, exp - 1);
        }

        double term(int numr, long denom) {
            return(numr / denom);
        }

        void findSum() {
            int u = 2, l = 4;
            sum = 1.0f;
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                if(l % 8 == 0) {
                    sum += term(power(x, u), fact(l));
                    // Test start
                    System.out.println("add" + sum + " power " + power(x, u) + " fact " + fact(l) + " x " + x + " u " + u
                            + " l " + l);
                    System.out.println("term " + term(power(x, u), fact(l)));
                    System.out.println("test term " + term(5, 2)); // printing 2.0
                                                                    // instead of 2.5
                    // Test end
                } else {
                    sum -= term(power(x, u), fact(l));
                    // Test start
                    System.out.println("minus" + sum + " power " + power(x, u) + " fact " + fact(l) + " x " + x + " u " + u
                            + " l " + l);
                    System.out.println("term " + term(power(x, u), fact(l)));
                    // Test end
                }
                u += 2;
                l += 4;
            }
        }
    }
```

//double term(int numr,long denom)
//{return (numr/denom);}
This function is not returning double value. Please help... This program is find a sum a series upto n terms. Example - test term is returning 2.0 instead of 2.5... Thanks.

Comment: read http://books.google.md/books?id=h0d8hVA5HyQC&pg=PA20&lpg=PA20&dq=int/long+result+type+java&source=bl&ots=AWOlnHTes6&sig=sPJGWGqyx-1oi2u1mCHN_bs-X3M&hl=en&sa=X&ei=VQLLUNL-EIv54QTXnYHICQ&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=int%2Flong%20result%20type%20java&f=false

Comment: hey, be nice to him - it's his first question..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cast explicitly to double before devision.

```
double term(int numr, long denom) {
     return ((double)numr / denom);
}
```

Comment: +1 I suspect the `numr` and `denom` should be `double` as well.

Comment: @fb-np1810 I suggest you change your `num` to use `double` in your other functions as well.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Okay i will... Thanks once again..!!

Answer (score 1):

The casting to `double` is done on the value resulting from the division, so you can read

```
double term(int numr,long denom) {
    return (double) (numr/denom);
}
```

So `numr/denom` is evaluated first, and since `int/long` type is long, the result would be 2L. Then it is casted to double. If you want it to be evaluated a double, do

```
double term(int numr,long denom) {
    return  ((double)numr/denom);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
double term(int numr, long denom) {
    return ((double) numr/denom);
}
```

your version had `int/long` which will always return a non floating point number.

See this:

```
int a = 2;
int b = 4;
double c = a/b; // 0.0
double d = ((double) a/b); // 0.5
```

Comment: Thank you... answer explains well.. @jlordo

Answer (score 0):

```
double term(int numr, long denom) {
    return (numr / denom);
}
```

The return value is `double` but the devision `(numr / denom)` creates a `long` which then is converted to double.

Answer (score 0):

This may help.

```
double term(int numr, long denom) {
    return ((double)numr / denom);
}
```